# Image not properly positioned

Tags: html, css

The image starts 3/4 way down the `div` and I can't understand why - I want it to be at the top, the text should be on the left and the image on the right.

I've played around with float, clear and inline display but nothing changes it.

html

```
<div class="ipslist">

  <p><strong> Why choose IPS Fire & Security? </strong></p>
  <br />

  <ul>
    <li> Service 365 24/7 </li>
    <li> Engineer on site within 4 hours </li>
    <li> Insurance Approved </li>
    <li> Established over 10 years </li>
    <li> We are the UK's most loved security service! (thebestof)</li>
    <li> SSAIB & BAFE Accreditation </li>
    <li> 24 hour technical support</li>
  </ul>

  <img src="Images/vanbluefence.jpg"/>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.ipslist{
  height: 250px;
  width: 950px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;    
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.ipslist img {
  float:right;  
}
```

Comment: `float: right;` means "float right of the following content", but your image is the last thing. You could move the image to the top of the code, or float your content left.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` to `ul`

`Ul` is block element so it is occupying the entire space and pushing image to next line.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ledahawi/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute positioning on the image, but ensure the container isn't positioned as static (the default).

```
.ipslist {
   height: 250px;
   width: 950px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;  
   font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
   position: relative;
 }

.ipslist img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

Comment: perfect, thanks for your help! any chance you could explain why its doing this so i learn for next time?

Comment: Because your image is after the rest of the markup, and the `ul` is set to `display: block` by default, this means the text takes up all the available space at the top, so the image has to display below it.
If you set your text elements to `float: left`, you might have been able to do it the way you originally tried. You could also have set the `ul` to `display: inline-block` to prevent it taking up all the space.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off wrapping all your text in a div and floating the div left.

**HTML**

```
<div class="ipslist">
    <div class='content-wrapper'>
        <p><strong> Why choose IPS Fire & Security? </strong></p>
        <br />
        <ul>
            <li> Service 365 24/7 </li>
            <li> Engineer on site within 4 hours </li>
            <li> Insurance Approved </li>
            <li> Established over 10 years </li>
            <li> We are the UK's most loved security service! (thebestof)</li>
            <li> SSAIB & BAFE Accreditation </li>
            <li> 24 hour technical support</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="Images/vanbluefence.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ipslist {
    height: 250px;
    width: 950px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;  
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.ipslist .content-wrapper{
    float:left;
    width: calc(100% - <width of image>)
}
.ipslist img {
    width:<width of image>; height:auto; 
    float:right;
}
```

Additionally, you can also `float:left` both the `.content-wrapper` and image and then apply `clear:both` on the `img`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/cv8M6/

Put image after ipslist and add

```
.ipslist{
    float:left;
}

#floatingImage{
    float:right; 
}
```